# Can I move Google calendar events from one user to another user via API with a Service Account

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have created a Service account and I need to move event1 from calendar1 of User1 to calendar2 of User2.

When I request access token as User1 with "sub":"user1@gmail.com" during JWT step and using that token When I do following

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/User1calendarId/events/event1Id/move?Destination=user2calendarId
```

I get following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "calendar",
                "reason": "requiredAccessLevel",
                "message": "You need to have reader access to this calendar."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "You need to have reader access to this calendar."
    }
}
```

Are there any permission that needs to be assigned to Service Account in order to make this operation? or What should be correct way to move event between different user's calendar as a Service Account?

Comment: What scopes have you added into your service account when the JWT is created?

Comment: @CarlosM it has https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events scope

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

The scopes you are adding to your application are classified as **sensitive scopes**, as they request access to private user data such as Calendar events.

[image]

Your application would need to undergo a verification process to be able to use these scopes. For more information, please check the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#sensitive-scopes).

> **Sensitive scopes**

> Some of the scopes used by the following APIs are considered sensitive; see the API documentation or look for the lock icon in the Cloud Console. If your app requests sensitive scopes, and doesn't meet any of the criteria for an exception (see below), you will need to verify that your app follows the API Services User Data Policy.

> For a complete list of Google APIs, see OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs. To check if scopes are sensitive or restricted, add the scopes to your project via the Google Cloud Console.